# Is a file opened in another application?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, cocoa

Is there a way for me to tell if a particular file is open in another application?

I have a feature I'd like to provide before opening a file in my application, i want to know whether the file is already opened or not.

I want to put the functionality that if its already opened in another application then my application  restrict the file to open it again to save the loss of information.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Adapt from the [source code of lsof](http://freshmeat.net/projects/lsof/)? Good luck :/

Comment: Rasel: I have read about the file handling but it cant support this type of testing.

Comment: Oh ... writing a multi-language source file is hard. I suggest you choose only 1 of `c++`, `objective-c`, `c`, `xcode`, or `cocoa` for your project.

Comment: you can give me the solution in any of the language. I can use all these in my application.

Comment: You can do something based on *lsof* as suggested above, but you need superuser access and, what if the other application opens the file after your application opened it?

Answer (score 0):

There is file locking for this kind of tasks:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case the file is being opened by the any other application and i am going to put the locks on the file.

Comment: Well, this kind of information is highly system dependend and only available through debugging and statistic interfaces. I don't think you should mess with it. What you _could_ do is using the kqueue-Interface to watch for changes of a file: http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/FileNotification/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but k queue will not give the feature to check whether the file is opened or not. It will only notify about the change of the files at particular location. Thats not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use "lsof" to see if the file is open.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_lsof.htm

Answer (score 0):

You must have implemented some solution by now but, the way i understand your design, I suggest against your it.

You should allow the user to open the file and check the for time stamps to find out if its been modified before allowing user to save the file (may be ask user whether to overwrite the file or save it as new file etc.).

Look at [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) API.

-Before you open the file note down the timestamp (`st_mtime`, see structure below)

-Let users modify the file.

-Before user saves the file check the timestamp of the file again `st_mtime` and if it differs then ask questions to the user.

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```